# How many bits does a 8086 store in one single memory address in the RAM?

Tags: memory, x86, cpu, ram, memory-address

The address bus of the 8086 is 20 bit wide. That means it can address 1048576 different addresses in RAM. Since the max. memory the 8086 could handle was 1 MiB, one single memory cell can store 1 byte.

So a random logical address like 0xffff0 has a "storage" of 8 bits or 1 byte.

A modern Core i7 has an adress bus of 36 Bit, meaning he can address 68719476736 different addresses. With one byte per logical address he can handle 68719476736 Byte or 64 GiB which is exactly the max. memory an Core i7 can handle.

Is that explanation correct, I think so right?

So since 30 years the max. storage of a logical memory address is exactly 1 Byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrong assumption is "max storage". No, the smallest directly addressable unit is 1 byte, and addressing goes in 1-byte increments, but there are commands that work on 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits, encompassing blocks of 1, 2, 4 and 8 bytes.

So while you can still read a single byte like in the times of the old, you can instead operate on a 64-bit word with one command, and using the 64-bit commands family operate on the same address space but modifying addresses/pointers in increments of 8, not 1 as was with single bytes.

So, while normally yes, each one physical address precisely corresponds to storage of 8 bits, you can instead use the address space as "sparse" where only divides of 8 are valid addresses, and then use each of them as a 64-bit storage location, exactly as if each *valid* address was corresponding to 64 bits of storage.

Comment: Modern x86 also has 128-bit load/store instructions (using SSE vectors or CMPXCHG16B), and even 256-bit with AVX.  Soon (AVX512), 512-bit (64-byte) vectors, operating on a full cache-line at a time.

Answer (score 2):

First: you seem to be stating opinions. This is not a forum.

Second, I think you are wrong on the logic and the facts.

1. facts: i7 can only handle 24Gb, not 64Gb (see [What does the “Max Memory Size” on the new Intel Core i3 / i5 / i7 CPU's mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/93163/what-does-the-max-memory-size-on-the-new-intel-core-i3-i5-i7-cpus-mean) and the [i7 datasheet](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/320834.pdf))
2. logic: The bus size need not directly affect addressing/addressable memory (though I suspect it *usually* does/did).

---

Quote from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088:

> The Intel 8088 microprocessor was a variant of the Intel 8086 and was introduced on July 1, 1979. It had an **8-bit external data bus instead of the 16-bit bus** of the 8086. The 16-bit registers and the one megabyte address range were unchanged, however. The original IBM PC was based on the 8088.

Comment: ok then it was wrongly stated here on wikipedia http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Mikroprozessoren_von_Intel#Core_i7_.28Bloomfield.29

but am i right with the 8086?

Comment: The 8086... it was the first 16 bit processor in the intel family; But it was backwards compatible with the 8088 (which was 8-bit bus). So I assume that for that reason it kept byte-addressing. I'm not sure how that all evolved with 80[23456]86 - the introduction of 386 protected mode probably fundamentally shifted the paradigm (but the processor still has the compatibility mode where it behaves like the old 80186) -- I recommend you look up more articles about addressing models for authoritative info. Meanwhile, why are you concerned about details of the 8086 (`produced from 1978 to 1990s`)?